# No decimal dot and no space with \si{} of siunitx, TeX Live 2016

Tags: siunitx

Using the `\si` macro of the `siunitx` package, LuaLaTeX does not render the decimal `.` and does not insert a small space when setting "3.8 kV".

Version information from the log file:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016)  (format=lualatex 2017.2.27)
```

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=11pt, twoside, BCOR=8mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}% for lualatex

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale=UK, 
  repeatunits=false, 
  per=fraction,
  separate-uncertainty = false} % 3.45(2)

\begin{document}
$\si{+3.8}{\kilo\volt}$

\[\si{+3.8}{\kilo\volt}\]
\si{+3.8}{\kilo\volt}
\si{+3.8(0.1)}{\kilo\volt}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: I get no . with xetex or pdftex either, so it isn't a luatex issue.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and is the spacing broken on your systems too?

Comment: yes. But it's too late to read the siunitx manual now. No doubt Joseph will pass by in the morning:-)

Comment: Of course the command should be `\SI`, not `\si`.

Comment: @egreg thank you. You are so right. I think I should wear new glasses.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP's issue is due to confusion between the \Si and \si macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is `\SI`, not `\si`. The latter is for typesetting a unit symbol alone.

I've also changed the “version 1“ keys.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=11pt, twoside, BCOR=8mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}% for lualatex

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale=UK,
  multi-part-units=false,
  product-units=false
  range-units=false
  per-mode=fraction,
  separate-uncertainty = false           
}

\begin{document}
$\SI{+3.8}{\kilo\volt}$

\[\SI{+3.8}{\kilo\volt}\]
\SI{+3.8}{\kilo\volt}
\SI{+3.8\pm0.1}{\kilo\volt}
\end{document}
```

Note the uncertainty is denoted with `\pm`.

[image]

Comment: The uncertainty written as 3.8(2) or 3.8+-0.2 will be converted internally by siunitx to `\pm` see `texdoc siunitx` page 20. "As with other signs, the combination +- will automatically be converted to \pm internally."